# Hamburger menu in html and css not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hamburger menu using the the  tag in html and then style it in css. But it is not showing on on the website.

This is the html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NEXT Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar__container">
                    <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">NEXT</a>
                    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="navbar__menu">
                        <li class="navbar__item">
                            <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar__item">
                            <a href="/tech.html" class="navbar__links">Tech</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar__item">
                            <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar__btn">
                            <a href="/" class="button">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And this is the css code pertaining to the menu:

```
.navbar__toggle.bar{
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin:5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background:#ffff;
    }

 #mobile-menu{
        position: absolute;
        top:20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
        display: block;
    }
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue of html or css, please let me know!

Comment: sorry, I just meant appearing! on the tutorial, once the instructor saves the code a button appears on the page, but it doesn't do that with mine!

Comment: what else did the instructor do? ... `once the instructor saves the code a button appears on the page` ... that does not happen without a web browser page reload

Comment: So basically it tells you to use an extension in vs code called live server and whenever you save the code it automatically refreshes the website.

Comment: If the “*toggle button*” to which you’re referring is the `div#mobile-menu` node in your markup, where have you defined the styles for it/its descendants? These elements wouldn't generally have stylings that would “appear” visually by default in a browser; you’d have to define their appearance as per your requirements within your CSS. Have you done this? If so, why haven’t you included the requisite CSS in your snippet such that it meets the guidance for creating a [mre]? This info would be very helpful in getting to the bottom of your issue.

Comment: not sure what the term is, there is not effects at which it appears or pop up or finesse itself onto the page. What I mean is that the button should be on the page but is not. Is this really related CSS? below is the code in css pertaining to the bars.
 `.navbar__toggle.bar{width:25px ;height: 3px;margin: 5px auto; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;background: #fff;}`